# PHP try-catch supports short notation?

Tags: php, try-catch, notation

Is this legal? Not near my work computer so can't test

```
try
    someClass::someStaticFunction();
catch(Exception $e)
    $e->getMessage();
```

Specifically the lack of brackets, similar to an if-else statement

```
if(someBool)
    someClass::someStaticFunction();
else
    someClass::someOtherFunction();
```

Cheers!

Comment: i know for sure the if else is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, doesn't seem like it works.

Check my example here: http://codepad.org/BpSBiPDY

Answer (score 6):

No you must use the brace brackets. Note that you can catch exceptions by type :

```
try {
  someClass::someStaticFunction();
} catch (MyException $e) {
  // do specific stuff for this exception
} catch (Exception $e) {
  // do stuff for other exceptions
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No it isn't, there's no alternative syntax for try/catch... it's only 8 characters plus the Exception $e... that's not exactly long

Comment: if the coding standard the company follows is either no brackets or each bracket has it's own newline, then it's rather obnoxious

Comment: What's obnoxious? If a company has those code standards, then you should be adhering to them anyway, so all code should then look "obnoxious"... and any company that has a coding standard like that is also unlikely to permit alternative syntax either... but code quality isn't normally measured by how pretty the source text looks on a screen.

Comment: @PandemoniumSyndicate Indeed it is and I personally hate writing brackets for one-line expressions, but try-catch seems to be the only construct that doesn't have an alternative syntax.

Comment: @Narf I mean, of the constructs where an exception to the rule would be made, try-catch seems a very reasonable one to make. But still...

Comment: Yeah ... I know - it's a pain in the ass.

Answer (score 0):

try-catch require mandatory brackets in all the languages that I know (C#, JavaScript, etc.);

I think the reason is to avoid since the begin the (little or big) mess up that come, for example, from the `if()` construct because it supports the lack of brackets AND the OPTIONAL else part;

for example, in the code:

```php
if(a==0) if(b==3) ++a; else ++b;
```

to which `if()` is referring the `else` part?

We all surely know that, in the above code, the else part refer to the 2nd `if()` (the nearest `if()`), but sometime it make confusion when you are fast typing code (or fast checking code that is already typed), and all know this too.

So, because in `try` `catch` (and `finally`), the `catch` and the `finally` parts are optional, and the `catch` part can even be repeated (I mean, you may put more `catch` parts for different kind of errors to be caught), I think the designers of the languages wanted to avoid since the begin the potentially ambiguities that can come from the missing of brackets is some critical cases.